# Laravel session id does not match in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, session

I have a question about linking my database tables to my session table in Laravel 5.6.

I wanted to link who ever creates an email address in the `user_emails` table to the `session` table, so that in future I may be able to retrieve details about that transaction - like the ip address.

I am using the following code:

```
$email = new UserEmail();
$email->user_id = $user->id;
$email->address = $request->email;
$email->token = str_random(30);
$email->session_id = session()->getId();
$email->save();
```

This will save the `session_id` field as (in this example) `UkPhMBTVq73MX8KaS8CZy0vDG9wtDSNvSYhsRuvL` inside the user_emails table, with a `user_id` of `62`.

However, when I check the `sessions` table for the entry with `user_id = 62`, the `id` field is set to `DuQq6JqcFL2HiGGLGJQ9hLNeXaxUAkdYTlJEX1Ag`.

It appears to me that the session id is changing immediately whilst saving the entry to `user_emails` table. This also means I am unable to create a foreign key between `user_emails.session_id` and `sessions.id` as it throws a foreign key constraint issue.

Is this intended behaviour? I expected that the sessions table would create a new row for each new session, as opposed to overwriting the existing row.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this. It would be nice to be able to link activity to the `sessions` for future analysis. My logic in this case would be to check where the request originated from, should the User report the registration as as unauthorised when they receive their welcome email.

I of course have the session driver set to database, so that Laravel stores all my session data automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this page. I found that the reason for this was that I was logging the user in with the new email immediately after saving the information to the database. According to the Laravel docs, the session ID is automatically changed and updated with each login - for security reasons.

It looks like I'll need to look in to a logging package to track activity over sessions, and that just storing the IP address in this case would be best.